# High School Textbook Recommendation

Tags: resource-request, textbooks

Please recommend an introductory linguistics textbook for motivated high school students.

Comment: Not a great fit for the site (no one right answer), but I like Grady & Archibald.

Comment: https://www.macmillanlearning.com/college/us/product/Contemporary-Linguistics/p/1319039774?selected_tab=Contents (O’Grady et al.)

Comment: David Crystal's _Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language_ and  _Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language_ should be enough. They're good reading and cover everything. Best of all, they're not textbooks.